# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyhdbcli' for HANA Client 2.2.36

Tags: python, hana, pypi

I have installed HANA Client Python driver and package hdbcli-2.2.36 as per link https://help.sap.com/viewer/1efad1691c1f496b8b580064a6536c2d/Cloud/en-US/39eca89d94ca464ca52385ad50fc7dea.html

module in Pypi https://pypi.org/project/hdbcli/

But i am getting below error when i try to connect to HANA DB from Jupyter

*
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
      1 import sys
      2 
----> 3 from hdbcli import dbapi
      4 
      5 connection = dbapi.connect('********', *****, '*****', '******')

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\hdbcli\dbapi.py in 
     10 import sys
     11 
---> 12 import pyhdbcli
     13 from .resultrow import ResultRow
     14

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyhdbcli'
*

Can you please let me know hdbcli package has any dependencies and How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is resolved after uninstalling older version(2.2.36) of hdbcli and installed latest version from  https://pypi.org/project/hdbcli/